# Why do django templates render dictionaries so slowly?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, jinja2

When I render a moderately complex dictionary (4 levels deep, ~2K data points) using django 1.4's default template system the template rendering step takes over 2800ms.  When I do html-gen directly from python instead it takes ~80ms.  Even using another template library ([jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/)) renders the same data (in fact, almost exactly the same template syntax - as jinja2 is nearly a drop-in replacement) in under 300ms.

Interestingly, you don't even have to actually *render* the dictionary in the template to cause this performance issue in django's template system... all you have to do is *pass* it as an available variable to a template.  A friend of mine suggested this may mean the system is, "...doing a defensive copy or (more stupidly) a comprehension [which] will take time due to running constructors"

Anyone know why django's default template system takes so long to render dictionaries?

*** I'll work on adding requested details below ***

I am running in debug mode and have the DebugToolbarMiddleware set as one of my middleware classes.  My settings.py file includes:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

and....

```
# rendering like this
return render(
    request,
    template_name='ltm/search_results.html',
    context_instance=RequestContext(request, {
        'menus': menus,
        'results': result_dict
    })
)
```

Comment: Why don't you cProfile runserver instead of us guessing? We don't have your data. Do you have any fancy context processors?

Comment: Could you provide a runnable example with dummy data?

Comment: Does not answer your question, but worth giving it a look: [Jinja2 adapter for Django](https://github.com/GaretJax/coffin).

Comment: @PavelAnossov... +1 short answer?  because that's the first I've heard of cProfile :)  i'll work on that and post an update.  may take some time because i'm working against a deadline and was able to sidestep this issue using jinja2 and move on to other issues.  was just curious whether this was a known issue by someone more experienced.  but you make a good point, it could very well be something specific to my setup.

Comment: Jinja2 performs a lot better than Django templates.

Answer (score 2):

It would be great if you could provide us with your template code to better understand what kind of template processing we're dealing with exactly.

Firstly, there are potential differences between how your traversing the contents of the dictionary. `dict.items()` returns a list of tuples which consumes additional memory and takes time to initially construct, but it's faster to access keys and values than through a generator if you used `dict.iteritems()`.

There's also some overhead involved when you pass in variable names preceded by a dot `.`, e.g. `foo.bar.baz`, where Django's template performs what's called a [*variable lookup*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups), trying to determine whether your accessing a dictionary item by key, an object's attribute or a list item by index. I haven't used Jinja2, so the issue with variable lookups might be completely unrelated, but it is something worth considering if there's a difference between the two.

In either case, since your dealing with a fairly large dictionary, it might help if you could reorganize it's structure in the view to simplify how the data is accessed later in the template.

Comment: Thank you for posting this.  It kills me that I haven't had time to update my question.  When I do I plan to try to reproduce the behavior using a very simple example.  In my testing I tried both items() and iteritems().  I was very concerned that there was something about the way I was referencing the dictionary in my template that was causing the problem.  That's why I tested replacing with a "hello world" template.  It's important to understand that this made almost no difference in rendering time.  For that reason I'm pretty sure the sluggishness is unrelated to the actual rendering.